# How do I get values with the name being the only unique value?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

[Screenshot with input and expected output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Q7bk.jpg)

I tried using unique but it only does it if ALL column values in the range are the same. I only want the name to be unique!

Thanks all in advance :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In E1 try this formula

```
=ArrayFormula(iferror(vlookup(unique(A:A), A:C, {1,2,3}, 0)))
```

and see if that works?

Comment: thanks it did!, but what if the range in the vlookup is a query? it shows up blank! but this is a much more complex query: =ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(UNIQUE(A2:A),QUERY('Log in'!A1:M35028,"Select A, B, E, F, G, L, M Where K = "& YEAR('Daily Report'!B2) &" AND J = "& 'Daily Report'!C2 &" AND L >= 2 AND C is null ORDER BY G, B",1),{1,2,3,4,5,6,7},FALSE)))

Comment: Can you share a copy of your spreadsheet (sensitive data erased) ?

Comment: I added "ERROR" 2nd parameter to IFERROR, it showed ERROR on A1-G1, I removed everything except the =Query like before and it's fine... i guess it is not about the query, does it have sth to do with query in a vlookup, never tried that before

Comment: good news, i have managed to solve it... =ArrayFormula( IFERROR( VLOOKUP( UNIQUE(Sheet12!A2:A), Sheet12!A2:G, {1,2,3,4,5,6,7}, FALSE ) ) ), i had to make a new sheet... is there a better way to do it without creating sheets? It takes data from a sheet with query, then my new sheet takes data from that sheet similar with your formula...